# Build string from regex

Tags: regex, string, scala

my case is that I have a regular expression in my code that is used to match against various end points that a user can subscribe to for data (e.g. `"some/end/(.+)/point".r`; a bit like REST end points) where the regex allows the user to specify an ID for some object they want to subscribe to so they don't get out the entire collection the end point can represent.

My problem now is that I would like to reconstruct a specific end point when I have the ID of the element. In other words, I would like to build a string by supplying the ID to this regex in some way so it will produce the desired end point string, but without duplicating the data.

How can I best accomplish this? 
Should I store the end point regex as a string instead? (allowing me to go `"some/end/(.+)/point".replaceAll("(.+)", myId)`)
Or is there a nice way of doing this "reverse" regex matching?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use string interpolation and switch to regexp:

```
def endPoint(id : String) = s"some/end/$id/point"

val pattern = "(.+)"
val EndPointPattern = endPoint(pattern).r
println(s"EndPointPattern = $EndPointPattern")

val EndPointPattern(idFound) = "some/end/JohnDoe/point"
println(s"idFound = $idFound")

val endPointString = endPoint(idFound)
println(s"endPointString = $endPointString")
```

Comment: Thanks, building it up this way seems like the most sensible thing to do :)